# Is it known whether there exist arbitrarily large gaps between consecutive Carmichael numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Do you have any references in the literature where an argument is given to answer this question? Is it a well known result? If it is, a simple Google search returned nothing. By a simple brute force search, I will have to bet that the existence of such gaps is unlikely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an elementary (constructive) argument for unbounded gaps between Carmichael numbers.

Carmichael numbers are known to be square free. We can make arbitrarily long strings of non-squarefree numbers using the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

Let $p_k$ be the $k$th prime in increasing order ($p_1=2,p_2=3,...$). Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find $n$ so that

$n\equiv 0\pmod{2^2}$ and

$n+1\equiv 0\pmod{3^2}$, and

$n+2\equiv 0 \pmod{5^2}$, and

...

$n+(k-1) \equiv 0\pmod{p_k^2}$

This gives $k$ consecutive non-squarefree numbers, and hence non-Carmichael numbers.

Comment: Also, a good trick about consecutive square-free numbers! :)

Answer (score 5):

Pomerance proved an [upper bound](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-37-156/S0025-5718-1981-0628717-0/) for the number of Carmichael numbers less than $n$:

$$C(n)<n\exp\left(-\frac{\ln(n)\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))}{2\ln(\ln(n))}\right)$$

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C(n)}{n}=0$$

the average distance between Carmichael numbers must go to infinity. Thus, the sequence defined as the difference between consecutive Carmichael numbers is unbounded.

Comment: That upper bound is due to Erdős, not Alford, and should also have a constant in the exponential term. See here: https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1956-10.pdf

Comment: For reference, Alford's work (joint with Granville and Pomerance in 1994) was to prove a *lower* bound (of $n^{2/7}$) on $C(n)$, not an upper bound.

Comment: My mistake, the mathworld link had the lower and upper bound right next to each other. Pinch proved the upper bound without the constant (at least according to the site)

Comment: I think that link has some incorrect info. As far as I can tell, Pinch's work on Carmichael numbers appears to involve numerical computations of the distribution up to $10^{21}$, not proofs of asymptotic bounds. [Pomerance showed in 1981](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-37-156/S0025-5718-1981-0628717-0/) that $C(x) \leq x \exp(-\frac{1}{2} \log x \log \log \log x/\log \log x)$ for $x \gg 0$, and conjectured that the $\frac{1}{2}$ can be replaced by $1 - o(1)$ to give the actual order of growth, but to my knowledge this conjecture is still open.

Comment: Duly noted, switched the source to the AMS paper.